# Submit data to a Web API using a DTO object as parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, asp.net-web-api, dto

I have this Ajax post function, linked to a button with an attribute "data-gig-id".
 When pressed the button call a Web API.
The example below is fully working, but i don't understand the reason why.
The ajax function is making a post request with a gigId parameter(?) then the controller is called and the object passed is the DTO that seems a wrapper with a property.

Can somebody explain me how the gigId variable in ajax post, is calling the appropriate DTO and is passed to the Controller? The gigId in ajax is lowercase, while the DTO obj is GigId (?).

I am very confused...

Thank u

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".js-toggle-attendance").click(function (e) {
            var button = $(e.target);
            $.post("/api/nameAPI", { gigId: button.attr("data-gig-id") })
               ... some code ...
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the DTO object associated

```
public class AttendanceDto
{
    public int GigId { get; set; }
}
```

Then i have a controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Attend(AttendanceDto dto)
    {
        ... some other code ...

        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) we can see that:

> For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message
>   body, using a media-type formatter.

This formatters can be changed in the API config, but I think by default for JSON the Newtonsoft (de)serialiser is used. The property name matching with this formatter must not require an exact match as far as case sensitivity is concerned.

Comment: Ok, so it explains the case sensitivity but how can the Post action know that AttendanceDTO has the property required? It is called in the Web API Controller as a parameter, but i miss the link between client and server code.

Comment: The API will take the POST's request body, and attempt to create an instance of the parameter's type, in your case `AttendanceDTO`.

Answer (score 0):

**Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API**

When Web API calls a method on a controller, it must set values for the parameters, a process called binding.

By default, Web API uses the following rules to bind parameters:

If the parameter is a "simple" type, Web API tries to get the value from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int, bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal, and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from a string. (More about type converters later.)
For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message body, using a media-type formatter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

**Media Formatters in ASP.NET Web API 2**

A media type, also called a MIME type, identifies the format of a piece of data. In 
   HTTP, media types describe the format of the message body.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters